# Calculating the area of a circle using php function

Tags: php

I need to create a function to calculae the area of a circle. The function should take in two arguments (a number and a string). The number should be the radius or diameter of the circle. The string should be the word "diameter". The function should return the area of the circle or a -1 for an error. Finally, the script should initialize test variables, call the function and display the results as a web page.

This is beginning PHP but I'm just having problems catching on. Thanks!

This is what I have so far but it doesn't return the -1 and I can't figure out how to do that.

```
$diameter = 4.0;
$pi = 3.14;
$title="Circle";

echo "<html> <head> <title> $title </title> </head> <body>";

function circleArea($diameter, $pi) 
{
    $area = $diameter * $pi; 
    return $area; 
} 

echo circleArea ($diameter,$pi); 
echo "</body> </html>";
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. And also, if this is homework, please tag it as such. Welcome to Stackoverflow btw!

Comment: So, what's the question?  What have you tried so far?  What problems are you having?

Comment: This is what I have so far but it doesn't return the -1 and I can't figure out how to do that. [code]$diameter = 4.0; $pi = 3.14; $title="Circle"; echo "<html> <head> <title> $title </title> </head> <body>"; function circleArea($diameter, $pi) { $area = $diameter * $pi; return $area; } echo circleArea ($diameter,$pi); echo "</body> </html>"; [/code]

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
function calculateAreaOfCircle($number = 1, $type = 'radius') {
  if(!is_numeric($number) || $number <= 0)
    return -1;

  // what type of number is it?
  switch($type) {
    case 'radius':
    default:
      $radius = $number;

      break;

    case 'diameter':
      $radius = $number / 2;

      break;
  }

  return pow($radius, 2) * M_PI;
}

// what is the area for the radius of 25?
echo(calculateAreaOfCircle(25));

// what is the area for the diameter of 30?
echo(calculateAreaOfCircle(30, 'diameter'));
?>
```

When you tell me what the string is for ... ;-) (I think I guessed it)

Comment: I think I'm supposed to use if-else instead of switch. The radius is 2.0 so the diameter would be 4.0. The code you did works great!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @rabbit: If this is the right solution for your question mark this answer as "correct" (left next to text)

Comment: This isn't the answer I need. See previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: So - what do you really need? Explain it clearly to me please.

Comment: Here's the code I've been working on today. It's working, somewhat, but has some errors that I don't know how to fix. Thanks.

Comment: No. That's not it. Thanks for trying, though. I just need it to calculate the area of a circle with a 4.0 diameter or return -1 if error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
/**
* 
*/
class mathAlgorithm
{
    public $pie;
    public function __construct($pie)
    {
        $this->pie = $pie;
    }
    public function AreaOfCircle($radius)
    {
        $pie = $this->pie;
        /**
        * Where Area of a Circle
        * A = πr2
        * Let   A = $area
        *       π = $pie
        *       r = $radius
        *   Where π = 22/7 or 3.142
        */
        $area = $pie * pow($radius, 2);
        $area = round($area, 2);
        return $area;
    }
}
$math = new mathAlgorithm(3.142);
echo $math->AreaOfCircle(2);
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
    $radius=2;
    $length=2;
    $breadth=2;
    $pi = 3.14;
    $area1= $pi * $radius * $radius;
    $area2=2*$pi*$radius;
    $rectangle1=$length*$breadth;
    $rectangle2=2*($length+$breadth);
    echo "AREA OF CIRCLE = $area1";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "PERIMETER OF RECTANGLE = $area2";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "AREA OF RECTANGLE = $rectangle1";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "PERIMETER OF RECTANGLE = $rectangle2";
?>
```

Comment: <?php
$radius=2;
$length=2;
$breadth=2;
$pi = 3.14;
$area1= $pi * $radius * $radius;
$area2=2*$pi*$radius;
$rectangle1=$length*$breadth;
$rectangle2=2*($length+$breadth);
echo "AREA OF CIRCLE = $area1";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "PERIMETER OF RECTANGLE = $area2";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "AREA OF RECTANGLE = $rectangle1";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "PERIMETER OF RECTANGLE = $rectangle2";
?>